# How to make use of Markups Core 'Callout' EditMode

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup-extensions, callouts

I am attempting to replicate the BIM 360's Design Review Editor's [callout tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNx55.jpg) (the most useful tool of them all) within my Forge app, but I can't seem to get the callouts edit mode from the Markups Core extension to work properly. When I change the editMode to 'callout', it seems to only create the text box at the end of the callout. So far, I've only been able to get this to work via a clumsy chain of eventListeners latched to the svg element that:
1. listen for the 'mouseup' event while drawing cloud,
2. switch editMode to arrow,
3. fire off a 'mousedown' event to begin new arrow,
4. listen for 'mouseup' event while drawing arrow,
5. switch editMode to callout,
6. switch editMode back to cloud when test has been entered.

Not only is it very clumsy, but it also ends up looking [absolutely horrible!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjKQ.jpg)

Does anyone know how to activate this tool properly, or if it's meant to work exactly as it does?

It really is a shame that we have to reinvent the wheel on so many of these tool that are implemented in BIM360... and used to be part of the Markups extension, but are now gone.
I'm really not a graphical interface developer, and if I have to become one, it will be years before I finish this app and my company can make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the *callout* tool from MarkupsCore properly. Unfortunately, the tool only generates the text box as you've observed. It does not generate the "cloud" rectangle and connecting line as in BIM360.

Comment: Btw. I've reached out to the Forge Viewer dev team and asked them to consider adding this "full callout" (incl. the cloud rectangle, the text box, and the connecting line) as one of the official markup tools.